# Quitar pantalla en negro

Tags: r

Tengo un autoejecutable .bat que carga un código en R. Ese código incluye una barra de progreso.

Si ejecuto el .bat suele salir una pantalla en negro, donde se ven las librerías que se van cargando etc..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si en el bat

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\Rscript.exe" --vanilla "fichero.R"
```

se puede añadir algo para quitar (o minimizar) esta pantalla en negro y que solo salga la barra de progreso.

Comment: Un BAT por definición te va a abrir una ventana de línea de comandos (la pantalla en negro), puedes redirigir la salida estándar para no ver lo que se ejecuta pero la ventana en negro la seguirás teniendo.  Para no ver esto, deberías investigar  alguna alternativa tipo vbscripts. Revisa esto: https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way

Comment: Pues he seguido el hilo y la pantalla en negro desaparece por completo, al menos a la vista. Hay que crear dos ficheros, el invisible.vbs y otro .bat, tal como dice la solución 1 del hilo. Gracias!!!